# Constrained optimisation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following problem:

Show that the candidate extrema of $f$ on the interior of $D$ are given by $P_1=(1,-1)$ and $P_2=(1,\frac{1}{3})$

$$f(x,y)=(y+1)(x^2-2x+y^2)$$

on the compact set

$$D={(x,y) ∈ \Bbb R^2\,\,|\,\, \phi (x,y) ≤ 0}$$

where,

$$\phi(x, y) = x^2 − 2x + y^2 + 4y − 4$$

---

To find the candidate extrema, the solution states that the Lagrange multiplier is equal to $0$. I do not understand why we would arbitrarily put $\lambda=0$, however, the candidate points are only found when $\lambda$ is, in fact, $0$. Could someone please explain this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a bad solution. In the interior of $D$, you set $\nabla f = 0$ and there is NO Lagrange multiplier application. To apply the method with $\lambda=0$ is erroneous. You apply Lagrange multipliers *only* on the boundary of $D$, namely, where $\phi(x,y)=0$, when you want the constrained extreme points. In the interior, there are no constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, for the stationary points on the interior you find the critical points by taking partial derivatives of the objective function, which is the Lagrange function when $\lambda =0$.

And note that
$$\phi(x, y) = x^2 − 2x + y^2 + 4y − 4\le 0 \Rightarrow \\
(x-1)^2+(y+2)^2\le 3^2$$
Both $P_1(1,-1)$ and $P_2(1,\frac13)$ lie inside the circle.